# Is glob in scalar context a lazy iterator?

Tags: perl

I quite like [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)'s often overlooked iterator-esque functionality.

What's not clear to me is whether it computes/loads the entire list into memory even when used in scalar context. In this example code, the `while` loop does not print anything to screen (4**24 is not a small number):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $opt = "{A,B,C,D}" x 24;
say while glob $opt;
```

---

Things I've tried/observed:

- I tried to eliminate the possibility of buffering being an issue by writing `1 while glob $opt;`, but it still takes forever and I end up <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>'ing out.
- Inspection of my memory usage via Windows Task Manager doesn't seem to show any difference when I run the script.
- Running `perl -MO=Deparse` only confirms that `glob` is being used in scalar context without indicating anything about memory usage.
- Running `perl -MO=Concise` results in the following output, which I don't know how to decipher:

  ```
  m  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
  1     <0> enter ->2
  2     <;> nextstate(main 49 -:5) v:%,*,&,{,x*,x&,x$,$,469762048 ->3   
  7     <2> sassign vKS/2 ->8
  5        <2> repeat[t2] sK/2 ->6
  3           <$> const[PV "{A,B,C,D}"] s ->4
  4           <$> const[IV 24] s ->5
  6        <0> padsv[$opt:49,74] sRM*/LVINTRO ->7
  8     <;> nextstate(main 74 -:6) v:%,*,&,{,x*,x&,x$,$,469762048 ->9
  l     <@> leave vK* ->m
  9        <0> enter v ->a
  -        <1> null vKP/1 ->l
  g           <|> and(other->h) vK/1 ->l
  f              <1> defined sK/1 ->g
  e                 <2> sassign sK/2 ->f
  c                    <@> glob[t5] sK/1 ->d
  -                       <0> ex-pushmark s ->a
  a                       <0> padsv[$opt:49,74] s ->b
  b                       <#> gv[*_GEN_0] s ->c
  -                    <1> ex-rv2sv sKRM*/3 ->e
  d                       <#> gvsv[*_] s ->e
  -              <@> lineseq vK ->-
  j                 <@> say vK ->k
  h                    <0> pushmark s ->i
  -                    <1> ex-rv2sv sK/3 ->j
  i                       <#> gvsv[*_] s ->j
  k                 <0> unstack v ->a
  - syntax OK
  ```

I'm running ActivePerl 5.16.3.

Comment: Interesting. I'd have thought that implicit in the `glob` was the need to expand the patterns, but I suppose it'll `just` iterate the current filesystem looking for matches as it goes.

Comment: @Sobrique : Would inspecting with `-MO=Concise` yield any clues? I don't know how to interpret the opcodes

Comment: it might, but I'm personally not familiar enough with it to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a glob pattern contains curly braces, a recursive function is called to expand the braces. See `ext/File-Glob/bsd_glob.c` in the Perl source*:

```c
/*
 * Expand recursively a glob {} pattern. When there is no more expansion
 * invoke the standard globbing routine to glob the rest of the magic
 * characters
 */
static int
globexp1(const Char *pattern, glob_t *pglob)
{
        const Char* ptr = pattern;
        int rv;

        /* Protect a single {}, for find(1), like csh */
        if (pattern[0] == BG_LBRACE && pattern[1] == BG_RBRACE && pattern[2] == BG_EOS)
                return glob0(pattern, pglob);

        while ((ptr = (const Char *) g_strchr((Char *) ptr, BG_LBRACE)) != NULL)
                if (!globexp2(ptr, pattern, pglob, &rv))
                        return rv;

        return glob0(pattern, pglob);
}
```

My C is rusty, but when I run your script in gdb and set a breakpoint on this function, it gets hit many, many, many times, suggesting a very deep recursion, and by extension, non-lazy behavior. Hopefully somebody who is more familiar with Perl's internals can elaborate.

---

* The above is from version 5.20.2.

Answer (score 2):

It does not appear to be lazy when you observe a delay between first glob invocation and first print of the result.  This is further corroborated by the time it takes to execute a glob in the scalar context *not* in a loop (in my example I used smaller exponent so that delay is still noticeable but not too long):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Time::HiRes;

$| = 1;

my $opt = "{A,B,C,D}" x 10;
say Time::HiRes::time;
my $x = glob $opt;
say $x;
say Time::HiRes::time;
say while glob $opt;
say Time::HiRes::time;
```

Comment: It feels so odd that the iterator has to evaluate all combinations first. I guess I can understand why it might be done when globbing a filesystem (`while <>`), seems like this behavior extends to strings that only contain `{}` wildcards.

Comment: @Zaid in fact I think in the "normal" case, all `{}` patterns are expanded *before* looking at the filesystem :)

Comment: @hobbs : And your statement looks to be confirmed by ThisSuitIsBlackNot's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30338126/133939).